# Redefine <TAB> key for triggering plugin action

Tags: key-bindings, plugin-snipmate

i've got a mapping for iterating thru suggested pop up window of omni completion

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<TAB>"
```

but i also want a  to trigger while there is no suggestions menu but a [snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/) shortcut `<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger` has been faced, but now only actual tab is inserted after an expression expected to be expanded.

**Solution**

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "<c-r>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<cr>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to call whatever `<tab>` is normally calling instead of issuing the tab key press. Something like:

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "<esc>:call NormalTabFunction()<cr>a"
```

The command that actually worked in this specific case was (resulting from the discussion in the comments):

```
inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : <c-r>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<cr>"
```

Comment: Could there be a slash missed, cuz it inserts a text `:call NormalTabFunction()` literally?

Comment: Sorry, missed the fact that this is an insert mode mapping. I changed the answer to include `<esc>` and `a` to get out of and into insert mode. This should work with a minor side effect: if the cursor is in front of the first character on the line, the cursor will move one space right. Since you're using this for completing, I'm not sure whether that matters.

Comment: error: Unknown function: NormalTabFunction()

Comment: With NormalTabFunction I mean the function that normally gets called when tab is pressed, sorry for being unclear about that. You might find this function by running `:imap <tab>`.

Comment: it's `<Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger()` if i insert it as is it says that _function name required_, if i specify it as `snipMateNextOrTrigger()` it says that _unknown function_, should i escape <Plug> in some way or smth else?

Comment: I actually ran into a similar issue yesterday. `<Plug>` can be escaped as `<lt>Plug>`, as in this question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/11839/8061

Comment: `inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "<esc>:call <lt>Plug>snipMateNextOrTrigger()<cr>a"` says _unknown function_

Comment: I don't have snipmate installed here, so it's hard to verify, but from the source code, the function name seems to be `snipMate#TriggerSnippet()`. Could you try `inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "<lt>C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<cr>"`? Found at https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/blob/master/plugin/snipMate.vim, line 40

Comment: inserts text literally `>C-R>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()`

Comment: Sorry, this is getting embarrassing. Try `inoremap <expr> <TAB> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "<c-r>=snipMate#TriggerSnippet()<cr>"`. `<c-r>` should not be escaped here as we want vim to simulate the ctrl-r keypress.