# mapping to map <return>

Tags: key-bindings

I'm trying to create a mapping to create a mapping such that pressing `<C-return>` presents me with `:nnoremap <return> :` to which I can then add a custom command. The following does not work because `<return>` is replaced by the return key.

```
:nnoremap <c-return> :nnoremap <return> :
```

I thought I could escape `<return>` as `\<return>`, but this does not seem to be working. How do I escape (or otherwise prevent nnoremap from expanding) `<return>` in the above statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape `<` as `<lt>`:

```
nnoremap <c-return> :nnoremap <lt>return> :
```

For more help see:

```
:h key-codes
```

Comment: Ah! I knew there was better way.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting I thought we could do this with an `exe` command, but that fails too. I found a way to do it but it's pretty hacky:

```
:nnoremap <c-return> :nnoremap <return > :<c-left><c-left><BS><c-right><c-right>
```

- `<c-left>`: executes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
- `<c-right>`: executes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>
- `<BS>`: executes <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

We're basically breaking up the `<return>` so that it's not recognized and then we go back and delete the space. This works, but I'm curious if there is a better way of doing it.